# Convert an ASCII list into an HTML list with Ruby

Tags: html, ruby, parsing

Given the following list:

```
links = %w(
  /foo/bar/baz
  /foo/bar
  /foo/42/43/44/test
  /foo/42
  /foo/test/test2
)
```

I would like to obtain an HTML unordered list such as:

```
<ul>
  <li>
    foo

    <ul>
      <li>
        <a href="/foo/bar">bar</a>

        <ul>
          <li><a href="/foo/bar/baz">baz</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>

      <li>
        <a href="/foo/42">42</a>

        <ul>
          <li>
            43

            <ul>
              <li>
                44

                <ul>
                  <li><a href="/foo/42/43/44/test">test</a></li>
                </ul>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>

      <li>
        test

        <ul>
          <li><a href="/foo/test/test2">test2</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

I through I may be a good idea to do it in functionnal style, with a method which call itself.  Have you got an example of code to do this?  Thanks a lot.

Comment: StackOverflow is not a free code-on-demand service. Please post your code and specific problems you may have with it.

Comment: @Sisss What have you tried to achieve this except posting this question?

Comment: Well, my personal tests were not a succes and by posting here I'm looking for the best method. Maybe there's already a pattern to do so. If you know one, please tell me.

Comment: @alok-anand: an example of code which can return such HTML, or a link to.

Answer (score 0):

1. Iterate strings on list
2. Scan the string with a regex something like /(/\w+)/
3. Iterate the scan results and build your html

I think that's just it .

OR you could use a some javascript to generate a tree-ish thing / whatever you need

Comment: Have you got a link to a such javascript plugin?

Comment: Thanks for this one.  Seems to be different however.  I'm continuing to search.